# isset function in php

Tags: php, mysql, database, isset

i was wondering if it 'is possible to get two isset function to work in 1 php file?'
and if not how to combine two isset function into one?
is there a simpler way to validate both recaptcha and the activation code in db?
much thanks if anyone could guide me with a simpler way...

Here is my current code recaptcha code:

```
 if (isset($_POST["recaptcha_response_field"])) {
        $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
                                        $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                                        $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                                        $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);

        if ($resp->is_valid) {
                echo "Account activated";
        } else {
                # set the error code so that we can display it
                $error = $resp->error;
                echo "please try again";
        }
} echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey, $error);
```

i would like to validate the registered user activation code as well so i created this:

```
if (isset($_GET['success']) === true && empty($_GET['success']) === true)
{
?>
    <h2> Account activated! </h2>
<?php
}
else if (isset($_GET['email'], $_GET['activation_code']) === true)
{
    $email      = trim($_GET['email']);
    $activation_code    = trim($_GET['activation_code']);

    if (emailadd_exists($email) === false)
    {
        $errors[] = 'Email address cannot be found';
    }

    else if (activate($email, $activation_code) === false)
    {
        $errors[] = 'Problem encountered activating your account';
    }

    if (empty($errors) === false)
    {
?>
    <h2> Oops </h2>
<?php
    echo output_errors($errors);
    }
    else
    {
        header('Location: index.php');
        exit();
    }
}
else
{
    echo 'error';
    exit();
}
?>
    <br/>
    <br/>
            <form action="" method="post">
        <ul>
        <li>
            Activation code:<br>
            <input name="activation_code" type="text"><br/>
            <input type="submit" value="Verify" />
        </li>
    </ul>
    </form>
```

how to combine the two isset function? or is there a simpler to do this...
please guide me. thanks in advance.

Comment: Combine how? What exactly are you trying to achieve and what's wrong with your current approach?

Comment: combine as in, use both isset func in one php file.
i want to validate both captcha and activation code in one php file when i click the 'activate' button.
but now only the recaptcha isset func can work...

the email and activation code isset func does not..
i was wondering if there is a simpler way to code which can validate the activation code of the registered user and recaptcha at the same time. thank you for any guidance.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to combine two conditions in an if-clause, simply use &&.
So this would be

```
else if (isset($_GET["email"]) && isset($_GET["activation_code"])) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Better still, [isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) allows multiple parameters.

> bool isset ( mixed $var [, mixed $... ] )

You can call `isset()` just one time with the same effect:

```
elseif(isset($_GET["email"],$_GET["activation_code"])){
```

> From the manual:
>
> ```
> $a = "test";
> $b = "anothertest";
>
> var_dump(isset($a));     // TRUE
> var_dump(isset($a, $b)); // TRUE
>
> unset ($a);
>
> var_dump(isset($a));     // FALSE
> var_dump(isset($a, $b)); // FALSE
> ```